# multiple graphs in one plot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data

| ID | Time | Score | Var1 | Var 2 | Var 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 150 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | -10 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | -70 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 200 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

I want to make a ggplot that combines all the variables together.
Y variable is = score.
X variable is = Time.
and for each categorical variable (i.e., var1, var2) I want to see the effect for each level.

My code for one Graph:

```
var1_graph=ggplot (DB, aes(Time, Score, group_by = ID))+
facet_wrap(~var1)+
geom_smooth()+
theme_bw()
#####Var2
var2_graph = ggplot (DB, aes(Time,Score, group_by=ID))+
facet_wrap(~var2)+
geom_smooth()+
theme_bw()
################
ggarrange(var1_graph, var2_graph, labels = c("A","B"), 
ncol = 1, nrow = 2).
```

But this isn't what I want because I want them to be in same plot and not to combine multiple plots.

Can do this using a "Pivot_longer function"?

Thanks!

Comment: please post data using the results from `dput(DB)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

`pivot_longer` is used to collect the vars in one column to enable faceting.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~ID, ~Time, ~Score, ~Var1, ~Var2, ~Var3,
  1, 1, 100, 1, 2, 1,
  1, 2, 150, 1, 2, 1,
  2, 1, 200, 2, 3, 4,
  2, 2, -10, 2, 3, 4,
  2, 3, -70, 2, 3, 4,
  3, 1, 100, 1, 2, 2,
  3, 2, 200, 1, 2, 2
) |> 
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Var"), names_to = "var", values_to = "level") |> 
  ggplot(aes(Time, Score, group = level)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(level ~ var)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Each var has 4 levels. so I want the graphs to be divided into 4 graphs for each level of var. 
all the graph have same x axis which is time, and same y axis which is score

Comment: Do you mean like this?